# Multivariate CDF with a Closed From

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, multivariate-distribution

Is there any multivariate distribution with a closed form CDF?

As we know, if $X_1,\;\ldots,\;X_M$ are i.i.d. type-1 extreme value distributed,
$\Pr[X_2-X_1<c_1,\;\ldots,\;X_M-X_1<c_M]$ has a closed form (the multinomial logit probability).

Is there any other multivariate distribution with a closed form CDF? (except the extreme value family)

Comment: What exactly constitutes "closed form"?  All multivariate distributions arising from independent collections of univariate distributions with closed-form CDFs (however that might be defined) obviously are of closed form, too.  What about distributions defined by copulas--would you count those as "closed form" when the marginal CDFs are in closed form?  If so, they offer an enormous range of possibilities.

Comment: @whuber I guesse, I made some unclear points due to my limited knowledge. The closed form consist of 1. an exact functional form 2. parameters in the function. For example, as far as I know, the multivariate normal distribution does not have a closed form CDF, which can be obtained by a numerical integration. So, what I meant by closed form is "a form that can be written without any integral or differentiation notations". I am not sure whether my point became. If you have any other ambiguous parts, let me know that:)

Comment: This sounds highly subjective, because to anyone familiar with the error function or the theory of "transcendental functions" generally, the Normal CDF *does* have a closed form--and they would use *precisely* your description to justify that conclusion! Indeed, could you give us any example of, say, the evaluation of a nontrivial value of the exponential function $x\to e^x$ that doesn't ultimately involve the equivalent of a numerical integration?  If you wish to point to, say, a power series or continued fraction approach, know that these work for the Normal CDF too.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the detailed explanation! Although there are confusing points for me due to my weak background, you gave me some directions that should be examined to solve my own problem. I guess, it may be informative for me to investigate the possibility you provided. Thank you for your service again!

Comment: Can you please write down the closed form of that CDF? Thanks!